# Tableau Public URL that Scrolls to a Specific Point in the Dashboard

Tags: tableau-api

I am creating a dashboard that will serve as a "landing page" for other existing dashboards. I want this landing page to contain a live view of the other dashboards. I am currently using web page dashboard items to link out to Tableau public dashboards.

These links would ideally show a specific part of the dashboard upon being opened so that the users can see the most relevant information immediately. Is there a way to manipulate the URL, or an alternative solution, to display the portion of the tableau public website that I would like?

I attempted copy and pasting worksheets over from these dashboards, however this would cause issues if the source dashboards are ever changed.

Answer (score 0):

Three possible solutions here:

1. Assuming this isn't a massive project, you could bring all the
   dashboards into a single workbook, build a 'landing page' dashboard
   in that workbook and use the navigation button objects to link
   to the dashboards or sheets you want your users to see (without
   opening a new tab in your browser).
2. You could make this 'landing page' dashboard as a separate workbook and use image objects instead of webpage objects. Edit the images to be screenshots of the desired dashboards or sheets and include the url to those dashboards or
   sheets and (if the user has access to them) they will be opened in a
   new tab.
3. Using URL dashboard actions; they work similarly to the image URLs with some extra functionality that actions provide but can be preformed on custom made sheets.